# Rails 4 Carrierwave Crop Slightly Off

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave, jcrop, uploader

I'm using carrierwave and jcrop to process uploaded photos. The issue is that the cropped photo is slightly off my expectations. The photo is cropped slightly to the right and down.

Below is my photo uploader file. I was guessing I might have done something wrong in this file because I know correct `x`, `y`, `w`, and `h` values are being passed to the uploader.

```
# encoding: utf-8

class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  def default_url
    # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
    # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))

    "/assets/default.png"
  end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :crop
    process :resize_to_fill => [50, 50]
  end

  version :medium do
    process :crop
    process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200]
  end

  version :large do
    process :crop
    process :resize_to_fill => [500, 500]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_white_list
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

  def crop
    if model.crop_x and model.crop_x.present?
      resize_to_limit(400, 0)
      manipulate! do |img|
        x = model.crop_x.to_i
        y = model.crop_y.to_i
        w = model.crop_w.to_i
        h = model.crop_h.to_i
        img.crop!(x, y, w, h)
      end
    end
  end
end
```